# ROracle, ORA-30204: buffer is not large enougth

Tags: r, oracle, rjdbc, roracle

When using ROracle library to connect Oracle to R, following error occurred (for "select" queries):
ORA-30204: buffer is not large enougth.
When using RJDBC library everything is OK, but very slow.
How can we avoid this error?

Comment: The destination buffer is not large enough for storing the selected data. Whats the size of the database buffer cache?

Comment: We suppose that problem can be solved using options string, like we did it with RJDBC: library(rJava); options(java.parameters = "-Xmx2048m"); library(RJDBC). Is it possible to set buffer size manually in ROracle? And how can we do it correctly? We tested ora.buf.size=-1, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

We avoid Error ORA-30204 after deleting all cyrillic comments in SQL script. So the decision is to change encoding parameters or eliminate cyrillic.